# How to inherit from, or override elements of, the Default style for a WinUI 3 control?

Tags: xaml, inheritance, winui

I am trying to learn how to use Styles most effectively in WinUI 3 (from WindowsAppSDK 1.1.1) but I'm having difficulty getting simple inheritance to work.

Consider the NavigationViewItem class. I'd like to modify the default style to bind the FontSize and Height properties. The following works in my Page XAML:

```
    <NavigationViewItem x:Uid="Shell_05" helpers:NavigationHelper.NavigateTo="ViewModels._05CreditViewModel"
                        FontSize="{Binding ViewModel.RootShellFontSize, ElementName=shellPage}"
                        Height="{Binding ViewModel.CurrentMenuItemHeight, ElementName=shellPage}">
        <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
            <BitmapIcon UriSource="\Images\credit.png"/>
        </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
    </NavigationViewItem>
```

But adding the two properties to a page resource does not (although the FontSize property works in each of the following. It's the Height that doesn't):

```
<Page.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="NavigationViewItem" >
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding ViewModel.RootShellFontSize, ElementName=shellPage}" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding ViewModel.CurrentMenuItemHeight, ElementName=shellPage}" />
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

Neither does adding the style to a resource dictionary and merging. I've read over what I can find about inheriting styles and the BasedOn="" extension is an explicit way to derive from an existing style in WinUI versions prior to 2.6 (I think). Apparently, WinUI 3 does not require BasedOn. In any case, simply specifying `TargetType="NavigationViewItem"` doesn't work, but nor does

```
<Style TargetType="controls:NavigationViewItem" BasedOn="DefaultNavigationViewItemStyle">
```

The source code for v1.1.1 of the SDK declares a default style for the NavigationViewItem in generic.xaml, but there is no definition for DefaultNavigationViewItemStyle.

I also cannot derive from the default style using

```
<Style TargetType="controls:NavigationViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type NavigationViewItem}}">
```

because `x:Type` is undefined.

I can do all of the bindings I want in code but I assume it's both clearer and more efficient to do it in XAML.

How do I inherit, derive from, or override a portion of the default style for a WinUI 3 control (not a custom control) in a desktop application, please?

Thanks for any help. Pointers to good XAML for WinUI 3 documentation (or books and articles) would also be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In your case the height is most probably not working since page.resources get compiled before object initialization and the height of the CurrentMenuItemHeight is 0. To solve it just set the mode to one way as such

```
{Binding ViewModel.CurrentMenuItemHeight,Mode=OneWay , ElementName=shellPage}
```

When you wish to use BasedOn, just say `BasedOn={ThemeResource styleName}`.
Just make sure the style is actually defined in Generic.xaml file which u can find in "C:\Users\AdminName.nuget\packages\microsoft.windowsappsdk\1.1.1\lib\uap10.0\Microsoft.UI\Themes"

So your final page.resources should be as such:

```
<Page.Resources>    
<Style TargetType="NavigationViewItem" >
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{Binding ViewModel.RootShellFontSize, ElementName=shellPage}" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="{Binding ViewModel.CurrentMenuItemHeight, Mode=OneWay, ElementName=shellPage}" />
</Style>    
</Page.Resources>
```

But it would be much better to use x:Bind instead of Binding. You can view this page to learn more about it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-in-depth